# Performance implications : Entity table reference vs List of that table reference

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am using entity framework and developing an architecture for application with remote data access. Coming back to point, i query the database for one record (say on the basis of itemcode). Now the resultset i will get whether i should return it as List or collection or simple as an object of entity. I am using entity object but my boss is saying i should use List. He thought , returning result as an entity with return whole table structure also. Quick suggestion would be appreciated.

```
List<Employee> lstemployee = GetRecordByCode(itemCode)
```

or

```
Employee emp = GetRecordByCode(itemCode)
```

Comment: If you are only getting one record from the database you should use an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the difference? If `itemCode` is a unique key you will either get one `Employee` object or a list containing the same one `Employee` object. You will never return the whole table. That will only happen if within `GetRecordByCode` you do something like `context.Employees.ToList()` without any `Where` filter before the `ToList()`.

If `itemCode` is not unique you even have to use a list.